# insert temp table with multiple select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, union, sql-update

I have a temporary table in my procedure; I tried to insert data from a select statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO #temptable
SELECT fee, expense, total FROM invoice 
UNION
SELECT vat, holdingtax, total FROM uplifts
```

...but in my *temptable*, only the first select statement gets populated into the table, while the next select statement does not insert the data.

Comment: try running only the `select`s (with `union`) and see what data you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the UNION is removing duplicated data.
I just made a test with union ALL:

```
insert into #temptable

select top 1 name from sys.tables
union  all
select top 1 name from sys.tables a
```

and I got `(2 row(s) affected)`

try to replace UNION by UNION ALL

Answer (score 2):

The syntax looks ok,

Its possible that there is duplication in the 2nd table.

You could test this using a Union All as opposed to Union.

I would just run the query without the insert to see if you return the results you expect.